# Install4j: logging in silent updater

Tags: java, install4j

During an installation process by Using `com.install4j.api.Util` I can log anything and the log is found in the .install4j directory. But while running the silent updater, I followed the same process but could not find where actually are the messages logged. Also if the logger used by Util does not work in this case, does install4j support using other logging libraries?

Comment: There should be no difference in unattended mode. There should be a file .install4j/installation.log if the updater downloads and executes a new installer. Just running the updater will not write a log file to the .install4j directory.

Comment: as I am not actually downloading a new installer rather patches/ zips, from which the update installation is done by custom actions, there is no way to use logs?

Comment: Got it, see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installer applications such as updaters write log files to the temporary directory (`%TEMP%` on Windows, `$TMP` on Linux/Unix, `$TMPDIR` on Mac OS X). Upon successful completion, the log file is deleted. To keep the log file, pass the argument

```
-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true
```

to the installer application. You can also add this as a fixed VM parameter on the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step.

If the temporary directory is an inconvenient location, pass the additional VM parameter

```
-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=[path to writable log file]
```

For debugging, there is also the possibility to write the logging output to stderr by passing

```
-Dinstall4j.logToStderr=true
```